# Rewriting logarithms as the ratios of natural logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have read this thread:

[Expressing logarithms as ratios of natural logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543640/expressing-logarithms-as-ratios-of-natural-logarithms)

It says this and I quote: " Consider $y=\log_b x$. Then, by definition, $b^y=x$ and so $y \ln b = \ln x$. Thus,
$$\log_b x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$$ "

**Could somebody please expand on this?** I know how logarithms work in general, yet why the statement

$y * \ln b = \ln x$

follows from

$b^y=x$

is beyond me. How does the natural logarithm play into that? I have only known the role of the natural base in the realm of continous growth or decay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion regarding the Logarithmic function change of base formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565912/confusion-regarding-the-logarithmic-function-change-of-base-formula)

Comment: Well, given the equation $b^y  = x$, we can take the natural logarithmm $\ln$ of both sides to get $\ln(b^y)=\ln(x)$, assuming $x$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. Then you simply apply one of the rules of logarithms $ \log(a^b)=a\cdot \log(b)$. Therefore, $y\cdot \ln(b)=\ln(x)$.

Comment: It comes from the Change of Base rule. The choice of $\ln$ is arbitrary, but presumably convenient in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one knows that
$$
\ln (x^y)=y\ln x,\qquad x>0,\,y\in\mathbb{R}, \tag1
$$ then applying
$$
A=B \implies \ln A = \ln B,\qquad A>0,\,B>0, \tag2
$$ to
$$
b^y=x
$$ gives
$$
\ln (b^y)=\ln x
$$ and using $(1)$ yields
$$
y \ln b=\ln x
$$ as desired.

Comment: It is more than clear now. Thank you for explaining it so succinctly